# Merge weighted averages in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a [Pandas `DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/frame.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "commodity":["Potatos","Potatos","Apples","Apples","Apples"], 
    "amount":[1,2,3,4,None], 
    "price":[4,5,6,7,8], 
    "attr1":[None,1,None,"foo","bar"],
})
```

(actually, I have a gazillion columns like `attr1` of different types).

I need to summarize the frame by `commodity`, keeping the ***first*** non-null `attr1` (and ***last*** non-null `attr2`).

Here is how I do it now:

```
df["cost"] = df.amount * df.price
def first(se):
    "Get the first non-None element of the Series"
    assert isinstance(se, pd.Series)
    se = se.dropna()
    if se.empty:
        return None
    return se.iloc[0]
summary = df.groupby("commodity").agg({"amount":sum, "cost":sum, "attr1":first})
df.drop(columns=["cost"], inplace=True)
summary["price"] = summary.cost / summary.amount
summary.drop(columns=["cost"], inplace=True)
columns = list(df.columns)
columns.remove("commodity")
summary = summary[columns]
summary

            amount  price       attr1
commodity           
Apples      7.0     6.571429    foo
Potatos     3.0     4.666667    1
```

This does what I want, but the function `first` seems to be unbearably expensive (as [expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26812763/850781)).

I wonder if this can be done more efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a custom `first`, there is already a [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html) (*and same goes for last*) :

```
firsts = ["attr1", ]; lasts = ["attr2", ] # add more for both if needed

fns = ({"amount": "sum", "price": "sum"}
       | dict.fromkeys(firsts, "first")
       | dict.fromkeys(lasts, "last"))

summary = (
    df
        # I added the chain below to create an `attr2`
        .assign(attr2=["a", None, "c", "", "b"]) # to remove
        .assign(price=df["amount"].mul(df["price"]))
        .groupby("commodity", sort=False).agg(fns)
        .assign(price=lambda x: x["price"].div(x["amount"]))
)
```

Output :

```
print(summary)

           amount  price attr1 attr2
commodity                           
Potatos      3.00   4.67     1     a
Apples       7.00   6.57   foo     b
```

Comment: Time went from 8min to 2sec (factor of 240)!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use `.notna()` + `.idxmax()`:

```
x = df.groupby("commodity").agg(
    {"amount": "sum", "attr1": lambda s: s.loc[s.notna().idxmax()]}
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
           amount attr1
commodity              
Apples        7.0   foo
Potatos       3.0     1
```

---

Or: `Series.first_valid_index()`:

```py
x = df.groupby("commodity").agg(
    {"amount": "sum", "attr1": lambda s: s.loc[s.first_valid_index()]}
)
print(x)
```

Comment: Alas, both `first_valid_index` and `idxmax` may return `None` thus necessitating custom functions with `try`/`except`...